# How do I rotate and object around itself, and translate it at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity, rotation, movement

I have this [animated gif](http://media.giphy.com/media/3oEdvaxO4P04B6fIcw/giphy.gif) of my problem.

I have a sprite object with a box collider, and I'm trying to rotate it around its center.

My rotation script consists of this :

```
this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
```

and in the translation script this is the code :

```
this.transform.Translate (0, -tranSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

but as you see in the gif it does not give me the effect I desire.
Can anyone give me what am I supposed to do to be able to rotate it around its center? Thank you.

Comment: `this.transform.Rotate(x,y,z,Space.Self)`

Comment: @Shiro Already had that code, did not help

Comment: that rotates an object around itsself. what do you mean by did not help ? what did you see and what did you expect to see ?

Comment: It gives me the exact same problem as in the animated image, what I want is the object keeping its rotation around itself, while translating.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the sprite you are using for the long square black rectangle thing?

Comment: @Jon I apologize. I tend to give horrible names when im frustrated.

Comment: Is that widget displaying at the *center* of the object, or the *pivot* of the object? Given your confusion, I suspect the two are not identical. This information is cropped out of your screenshot, but it'll near the top-left of your screen.

Comment: @rutter The pivot is the center of the sprite. I set that myself.

Comment: Do you mean for the object to translate in world space? If so, you will need to pass `Space.World` to the `Translate` method. If not, it will translate relative to its current rotation.

Comment: I know! :)@rutter I figured that out earlier. I wouldn't really give credit to you, but since you're the first one to mention that correct response in here, add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs on transform.Translate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html):

> public void Translate(float x, float y, float z, **Space relativeTo = Space.Self**);
>
> If **relativeTo is left out** or set to Space.Self the movement is applied
>   **relative to the transform's local axes**. (the x, y and z axes shown
>   when selecting the object inside the Scene View.)

So because you have not specified a space in which to apply the translation, it is applied relative to the object's current facing direction. As the object turns, so does its direction of travel.

You can fix this by setting transform.position directly, or telling transform.Translate to move relative to [Space.World](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.World.html):

```
this.transform.Translate (0, -tranSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.World);
```

Comment: Personally I recommend setting transform.position directly, but yes his explanation is completely correct

Comment: A third method is to nest your GameObjects' transforms, so you have an inner part that's spinning, and an outer part that's translating, so that the rotation doesn't affect the coordinate system used for any other behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your transformations might be accumulating over time. As repeatedly "stepping forward" and "rotating around your axis" will cause the black bar to walk in circles. I'm unfamiliar with Unity, but there are some general approaches that might be applicable:

1. You could try recalculating the object's position from its starting position, rather than from its current position.
2. You could try to make the translation transformation independant from the object's orientation. Right now, it seems the translation is using the black bar's orientation to calculate the local X-axis. Instead of a local coordinate system, you'll want to use the world coordinate system.
3. As a general remark, it is important to know that transformations are not commutative! This means that the order in which you apply them, can cause different results. As a general rule, transformations are mostly applied in this order: 1. scaling -> 2. rotation -> 3. translation. This makes sure your scaling and rotation don't cause a change in position. It also makes sure your scaling aligns with the local axes of the object.